# can the native portions of of a react-native package be run and developed standalone?

Tags: android, xcode, android-studio, react-native

Cross platform react-native packages have native android code, native iOS code, and javascript code that bridges them into the javascript world.

Presumably when working on the native portions of such a package you would import them into their respective IDEs (android-studio and Xcode) and do the UI development in the IDE.

When I look at react-native packages as a whole, or import the native portions into their respective IDEs, said native portions do no appear to be runnable standalone... at least not as a standalone android or ios application.

My question is how can you use the native IDEs to import/build/run/debug the native part of a react-native package? Would you typically still need the react-native server and rest javscript bridging code to be running?

The specific package I am looking at trying to modify native portion of is [react-native-datetime](https://github.com/cnjon/react-native-datetime/tree/master/android). My hope is to be able to import the android portion into android-studio and figure out how to run and modify one of the pickers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a static bundle of your js files for use in your app, you'll be able to run the app without having to keep the js server running. Then you should be able to work on the native code with the your editor/IDE using the `android` folder on your project directory (for android).

To create an offline bundle for android:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js \
  --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
  --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`

This should create a static bundle `index.android.bundle` for your javascript code under `android/app/src/main/assets/`

A simpler way would be to do

```
curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

from the build directory.

Answer (score 4):

React Native projects have on their root folder two other directories: `android` and `ios`, which have the Android (you can open it with Android Studio as any other Android project) and the XCode iOS projects respectively.

I would say that the react packager needs to be open so the app can fetch the JS files. I just tried closing it and running the app on XCode alone, and it opened the packager before on a terminal window.

My suggestion is: create an empty project, import that `react-native-datetime` package, use it on the main screen and play with it natively with Android Studio or XCode, if that's an option.

Comment: why create an empty project? shouldn't the android and ios folders within the datetime package already be Android Studio and XCode projects?... also if I import this particular package it doesn't seem to build since there is no declared react-native dependency (not sure if that is how a package should be?)... finally if I do add it as a dependency and am able to build it, it does not appear to be a runnable app (either that or I dont get how to  run a piece of UI code without having it be embedded in an app)

Comment: @funkyeah, You link the native code from the `node_modules` directory. So  you can just modify the code from there and then recompile. If you are looking for an easy way to preview components check out [react-native-storybook](https://github.com/kadirahq/react-native-storybook)

Comment: I'm looking to run only the native portion so it seems to me that node_modules would not be applicable... e.g. in the example datetime package I mentioned I would just want to render the timepicker